# set apoc.import.file.enabled=true in your neo4j.conf

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I have a Neo4j Java project perfectly working inside my Eclipse IDE.
I use APOC to load an XML file and process it.
Since now I have to deploy my project, I need to export a Runnable Jar file.
The problem is that, despite the system sees my neo4j.conf file with this setting:  *apoc.import.file.enabled=true*, at runtime I got this error:
**Import from files not enabled, please set apoc.import.file.enabled=true in your neo4j.conf**

It's pretty weird, because in the file I enabled the import from file with that string and the file is correctly detected.
Am I missing something?

EDIT: my neo4j.conf has only that line and works fine during the development mode in Eclipse.

Comment: How did you determine that the deployed "system sees my neo4j.conf file"?

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted the Neo4j after setting this line?
If not try after restart this may help.